# Как добавить класс элементу при появлении в зоне видимости браузера?

Tags: javascript

никак не могу найти способ, который решил бы мою задачу. В общем, вот фото:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно, чтобы при появлении элемента класс менялся на тот, который обведён. Я попробовал один скрипт, но он не работает. Помогите, пожалуйста.
Вот js

```
function come(elem) {
  var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
    docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height(),
    elemTop = $(elem).offset().top,
    elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

  return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

const l = document.getElementById("l1")

if (come(l1)) {
    l.classList.add("left")
}
```

Comment: Можно попробовать [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо навешать событие window.onscoll, внутри данного события проверять высоту расположения вашего элемента и позицию скролла.
https://learn.javascript.ru/onscroll
http://jsfiddle.net/eLwex993/2/

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  //ваша логика
}
```